# How to defend all my Assassin Dens against the Templar?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

In Assassin's Creed Revelations you have to reclaim Templar Towers (like the Borgia Towers from Brotherhood), but this time the Templar try to take them back.

Often I'm at the other side of town when they try to take it back, even worse often they are attacking multiple Dens at the same time. **So I'd like to know what an effective way is to defend them.**

Should I be using the sewers to quickly move closer or should I simply ignore the attacks and continue with the quests instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep in mind that you'll only be attacked if your Templar Awareness meter hits max and stays there for a given amount of time.  Just kill officials and bribe heralds every time you do something to raise it, and *you'll never have to worry about being attacked in the first place*.

(One thing to note that's a big difference from previous games - renovating property seems to add about **25%** to your meter!  It's really easy to max out if you're not careful.  Also, liberating a den in the first place seems to max it out every time, but you seem to have a few minutes to lower it before you risk an attack.)

Comment: Ah that's good to know, guess I should be more diligent about keeping a low profile then!

Comment: I also suspect that how quickly you get there determines how many enemies you'll face, but I'm not sure at this point.

Comment: Any idea what the "given amount of time" is?

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller - I think it's random, but I've never seen it go longer than 10 minutes or so.  Also, I'm still not sure if how long you take to get there affects the enemies you'll face, so there may not be any reason to rush once it triggers.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to have a master assassin (lvl 15 assassin) as Den master. Then the templars can't ever attack it.

So when you have all seven with a master assassin on, you never get any attacks.

Comment: Holy crap, what do I have to do to get one to level 15? Send them on countless missions?

Comment: You can do that, or I think they get a lot of XP when you give then the Den mastership and then do the master assassins missions. They are required anyway for your assassin to pass from lvl 14 to master assassin.

There are 2 by den.

Comment: You also have to finish the Master Assassin missions - these are NOT optional.

Comment: @Shinrai Only the first mission is mandatory, all other missions are optional. If you want Master Assassins, however, you'll need to do these missions, as they are the only way to promote an Assassin from lvl 14 to lvl 15.

Comment: @Shinrai Correction: The missions are the only way to get an Assassin past lvl 10 ;)

Comment: @Nolonar - As I read the comment I made, that's what I meant at the time.  "What do I have to do to get one to level 15?" "You also have to finish the missions"

Comment: @Shinrai I see. Sorry for the misunderstanding.